# Rest Framework Ember and sideloading

Tags: django, ember.js, ember-data, django-rest-framework

I am using Rest Framework Ember along with Django Rest Framework as my JSON API backend for my Ember application.

https://github.com/ngenworks/rest_framework_ember

I have gotten sideloading to work correctly with the resource_name = False flag. 
Here is my code below:

```
class DocumentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows documents to be viewed or edited.
    """

    queryset = Document.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DocumentSerializer

    # Side loading code for documents
    resource_name = False
    # renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer, BrowsableAPIRenderer)

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # import IPython
        # IPython.embed()
        data = {'document': []}
        for doc in self.get_queryset():
            data['document'].append(doc)
            data['contacts'] = doc.contacts.all()

        serializer = DocumentContactSerializer(data)

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

This works as I'd like it to work.

The problem now is that since I've implemented this and overwritten the list() method on the ModelViewSet whenever a new object is created on a POST I am getting this error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

If I comment out the resource_name = False then POST works as expected again.

Would you know what could be causing this?

Comment: Neat solution.  What version of DRF are you using?  I am looking to implement this myself.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the very same problem. Our set-up is also Ember + DRF. And I have found a solution.

You could override the `create` method like this:

```
def create(self, request):
    self.resource_name = 'document'
    data = request.DATA # returns the right querydict now
    # do what you want
```

In this way, you're keeping the side load by using `resource_name = false` in cases other than `create`.